# What is the depth distribution of a random binary tree with n nodes?

Tags: binary-trees, randomized-algorithms, path

Assume I generate a random binary tree with a bounded height with $n$ nodes.
For a given key we measure the length of its path (the maximum can be $n-1$). So my Question is what is the distribution of the path length?

The tree is constructed by recursively partitioning the given n points until all points are isolated or the tree height is reached. in each step of the recursion we choose randomly a split that is between max and min of the values that reach this node.

Would be great to know as much as possible regarding this distribution like expected value, variance and of course type and shape of the distribution.

Comment: What exactly is the probability distribution on trees or the random process used to generate the random tree?  Of course the path length has a distribution; what is is you really want to ask?

Comment: The tree is constructed by recursively partitioning the given n points until all points are
isolated or the tree height is reached. in each step of the recursion we choose randomly a split that is between max and min of the values that reach this node.

Comment: Please don't explain in the comments.  Instead, [edit] your post so it is self-contained, contains all relevant information, and reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Are you assuming all $n$ values/points are different?  Again, there certainly is some distribution -- you have just described a distribution.  What is your question?  Did you want to know something specific about that distribution, like its expected value?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I edited my question.

Comment: Ignoring the maximum height constraint, Reed "The height of a random binary search tree" proved that $\mathrm{E}[H_n] = \alpha \ln n - \beta \ln \ln n + O(1)$ and $\mathrm{Var}[H_n] = O(1)$.

Comment: Thanks @pcpthm, but you just wrote the average height search tree no? how is this related to the average depth of the nodes? it is not clear to me. Also what is $\alpha$ and $\beta$

Comment: @Jungle Sorry, I misread the question. I thought it is about the height of the whole tree (maximum depth), not the individual nodes. ($\alpha$ and $\beta$ are certain constants).